# Run :terminal so it starts in terminal-normal mode?

Tags: normal-mode, terminal-buffer

I want to run an async command and when it completes open a terminal window. Since the opening is delayed, I don't want it to steal input from me, so the new window should be in Terminal-Normal mode.

So far, the best I've figured out is opening it in a new tab and returning to the previous tab, but if I `gt` to that tab, it's still in Terminal-mode and I can't `gt` out of it without exiting to Terminal-normal.

```
function! project#run_after_compile(return_code) abort
    if a:return_code == 0
        tab terminal ++norestore C:\bin\run_game.bat
        tabnext #
    endif
endf
```

(I'm using this with [asyncrun](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim) to build with `makeprg` so errors go to quickfix then run in a terminal so its interactive: `let g:asyncrun_exit = 'call project#run_after_compile(g:asyncrun_code)'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `feedkeys`:

```
function! project#run_after_compile(return_code) abort
    if a:return_code == 0
        terminal ++norestore C:\bin\run_game.bat
        " Replace C-W if you have set 'termwinkey'.
        " Must pass "x" to allow other commands to follow (wincmd).
        call feedkeys("\<C-W>N", "x")
        wincmd p
    endif
endf

" Or put it in a tab:
function! project#run_after_compile(return_code) abort
    if a:return_code == 0
        tab terminal ++norestore C:\bin\run_game.bat
        call feedkeys("\<C-W>N", "x")
        tabnext #
    endif
endf
```

Note: Trying to be portable with `feedkeys(&termwinkey .."N")` doesn't work. I believe it's due to how you need to escape `<` for feedkeys.

Comment: Theres a term-specific feedkeys, but I forget what it’s called. You might also look at Dispatch

Comment: @D.BenKnoble It's [`term_sendkeys()`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#term_sendkeys%28%29). +1 for [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch).

Comment: `term_sendkeys()` send keys to the underlying terminal and not the buffer containing the terminal. `:call term_sendkeys(term_bufnr, &termwinkey ..'N')` inserts characters instead of switching to terminal-normal.